# Google Analytics 4 BigQuery Link: Event exclusion doesn't work

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-4

**Problem:**
Data Stream configuration (exclusion events) doesn't work. Datastream was configured on `20220621`. Even though daily limit is applied. Screenshot shows date and number of usage for one event. I would expect increase count from date `20220621`.

[image]

**Expected behaviour:**

- Export only events, that are **not tagged** for exclusion.
- I would expect increase count from date `20220621`.
- If I double check the `events_*` table with `intraday_events_*` table I see increase count in data, which is expected behavour. Limit is applied to [daily export](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11202874?hl=en). See screenshot - last row:

[image]

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Created a new GA4 Property
2. Setup the link connection to BigQuery
   [image]
3. Decided to configure Data Streams. Excluded certain events to get close to daily limit.
   [image]

**Few notes:**

- Configuration has been done by user1 who does have Owner permission in BigQuery and Admin permission in GA4 property
- Intraday is `20220627` (today's date)

Comment: What query did you use for the screenshots? I'm trying to understand the issue.

Comment: `select event_date, count(distinct user_pseudo_id) from <table> where event_name = "openLink" group by 1`
.. Query is filtering one event that is not listed in exclusion list.

Comment: What is your total event count per day from 20220621 to 20220627?

Comment: `20220621 34619;20220622 36206; 20220623 37949; 20220624 36304; 20220625 36258; 20220626 36006; 20220627 25750`
Query here:
`SELECT event_date, count(event_name) ct FROM project.events_202206* WHERE _table_suffix between '21' and '27' group by 1 order by 1`

Anyway I thought that maybe deletion and creation new link between GA4/BigQuery would help, but results are still same.

Answer (score 0):

Select all events you wanna exclude, then click Apply button. Then, be careful and search Save Button inside Bigquery Linking.